# How use same configuration for multiple ImageButton without copy pasting same attributes again and again?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing some layout for android application and using multiple buttons. all buttons are having similar attributes. It there anyway to keep similar attribute in some different file and refer on layout.

For example:

Below code is having multiple attributes. All are having similar values on all button excluding button id and icon. Is there any better way to avoid redefining again and  again?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/search_linear_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        >


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="78dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_schedule_black_48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="78dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_brightness_4_black_48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_below="@id/search_linear_layout"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="78dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_brightness_4_black_48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="78dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_local_hotel_black_48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Create a style in `styles.xml` using the common attributes and apply that style to the `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define different styles for your buttons and apply after that.
This [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) should be helpful.

**values/styles.xml** :

```
<style name="MyCustomStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/whatever</item>
</style>
```

**Your ImageButton inside layout file** :

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        style="@style/MyCustomStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Please make an separate .xml file for single button. and include that file where you want to use.

For example,
**my_button.xml**

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_brightness_4_black_48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3" />
```

Now call this layout in your required .xml

For example,
**activity_main**

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    layout="@layout/my_button">

</include>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Harsh, It helped me.

Comment: But here one small problem I have. How to I want to change icon and id for each button.

Comment: I got it . Using style I can achieve it.Anyway thanks for your suggestion. It helped me.